# Class UsersTableSeeders does not exist [ReflectionException]

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

```
    <?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeders extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       User::create([
                'name'=>'prakash',
                'username'=>'prakash',
                'email'=>'rockpokhrel@gmail.com',
                'password'=> bycrypt('pokhrel'),
                'remember_token'=> str_random(10),
            ]);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why i receiving this error : **[ReflectionException]
 Class UsersTableSeeders does not exist**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `composer dump-autoload` command on your terminal.

Comment: Weird why this works as i created a whole bunch of seeder classes prior to that and had no problems. I wonder if it happens when the default UserSeeder gets removed then added again at a later point (?)

Comment: Actually it DOES happen after you remove the seeder class and then add it again, you need to run the command in order to regenerate the autoload_classmap file which includes the seeder class.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add the tests directory in your composer.json like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests"
     ]
}
```

Run "composer dump-autoload" and "php artisan optimize" in the root of your project in terminal.